# Python Pandas apply using two arguments

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to pass values from 2 columns into a function via apply see mock up example below.
Here I want the function to return `John` if the first name is `John` but if it's not `John` I'd like to check the ID of that person against a dictionary which has a mapping of the ID against the full name and return that value.

```
d = {
    'Name': ['John:Smith', 'John:Carter', 'Jess:Wayne'],
    'Id': [12, 13, 14]
}

id_reference = {
    14: 'Jessica',
    15: 'William'
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)


def some_function(x, y):
    split = x.split(':')
    if split[0] == 'John':
        return 'John'
    if split [0] != 'John' and split[0] == 'Jess':
        return id_reference[y] 

df['Full Name'] = df.apply(lambda x: some_function(x['Name'], x['Id']))
```

Comment: @NovicePythoncharmer could you show expected [output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)?

Comment: expected output should be => df['Full Name'] = ['John', 'John, 'Jessica']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [axis=True](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). Here is an example:

```
d = {
    'Name': ['John:Smith', 'John:Carter', 'Jess:Wayne'],
    'Id': [12, 13, 14]
}

id_reference = {
    14: 'Jessica',
    15: 'William'
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)


def some_function(x):
    split = x['Name'].split(':')
    if split[0] == 'John':
        x['Full Name'] = split[0]
    elif split[0] == 'Jess':
        alias = id_reference.get(x['Id']) or ''
        x['Full Name'] = alias
    return x


df = df.apply(some_function, axis=True)
print(df)

#          Name  Id Full Name
#0   John:Smith  12      John
#1  John:Carter  13      John
#2   Jess:Wayne  14   Jessica
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option would be to [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the first names, then use them as the new value only [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) they are [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html)*qual* to `John` and if not, [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) their corresponding `id`*s* with the dictionary in order to bring the correct name.

```
fnames = df["Name"].str.extract("(.+):", expand=False)

df["Full Name"] = fnames.where(fnames.eq("John"), df["Id"].map(id_reference))
```

Output :

```
print(df)

          Name  Id Full Name
0   John:Smith  12      John
1  John:Carter  13      John
2   Jess:Wayne  14   Jessica

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```